# Out of memory error trying to fetch 1 Eloquent record when eager loading BelongsToMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have this query:

```
Order::find('1234')->refunds()->with('orderItems')->get()
```

This causes an out of memory error exhausting 256 MB to fetch one row with the loaded `items` also having only one row.

If I try this, I have no issues:

```
Order::find('1234')->refunds->first()->orderItems
```

It is only when I do eager loading.

My pivot definition:

```
public function items(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(OrderItem::class)
        ->using(OrderItemRefund::class)
        ->withPivot([
            'amount',
        ]);
}
```

When I look at the query it is failing on in the trace, I see the following:

```
SELECT
    `order_items`.*,
    `order_item_refund`.`refund_id` AS `pivot_refund_id`,
    `order_item_refund`.`order_item_id` AS `pivot_order_item_id`,
    `order_item_refund`.`amount` AS `pivot_amount`
FROM
    `order_items`
    INNER JOIN `order_item_refund` ON `order_items`.`id` = `order_item_refund`.`order_item_id` 
WHERE
    `order_item_refund`.`refund_id` IN ( 0 ) 
    AND `order_items`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

The key problem appears to be how Eloquent is internally constructing the part `refund_id IN ( 0 )` where it isn't adding the relevant `refund_id` value for the pivot table. If I run this as a raw query on the DB it returns all records satisfied by the join without filtering by `refund_id` which would have produced only a single record.

The bindings for the pivot query are empty when checked:

```
{
    bindings: [], 
    connectionName: mysql, 
    executionTimeMs: 8663.32
}
```

However, all the bindings for the queries Eloquent executes before that until the pivot have the expected values.

I've also further discovered this is impacting **all** relationships in **all** models that use `BelongsToMany`. The code only started acting up after upgrading to Laravel 8 (specifically we're on v8.83.14).

I've tried downgrading both Laravel and Doctrine to earlier minor versions while still remaining on v8 but that didn't help.

Comment: it is very weird, you would need to show `Order` model and the pivot table model just to see you are not loading anything else behind scenes

Comment: just to be sure, any of the tables that involved doesnt have `blobs` in it right? especially that `items` given you are loading tons of them.

Comment: It is not one model. It is all refunds along with all items of each refund that belongs to order 1234. In second case you take one refund explicitly.

Comment: Come to find out, this is happening with ALL of the BelongsToMany relationships on every model. Edited the question to include new data I found while digging further into it. Does not happen in Laravel 5.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 6 the primary key is now cast to integer unless explicitly set to string.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#eloquent-primary-key-type

The reason this happened is because we upgraded from Laravel 5.4 to Laravel 8 and have primary keys that are string based.

Setting the following on relevant models fixed the issue:

```
protected $keyType = 'string';
```